# allow multiple get methods in same controller web api asp.net

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
public class UserController : BaseApiControllerAuth
{
public ArrayList GetPermissions()
{

    enter code here

}
public UserModelCollection Get()
{

}
public UserModelCollection Get(fromuri id)
{

}
}
```

my webapiconfig file Route is

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Defalutapi2",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "All", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
       );
```

1.api/user/ is working
2.api/user/123 is working 
3.api/usr/Permissions gives error Multiple actions were found that match the request

how i can solve this ???

Answer (score 0):

Why you do not use web api 2 attributes routing instead of the traditional one?

You can do the following using attribute routing:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("ObtainData")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ObtainData(string input){}

[HttpGet]
    [Route("ObtainData2")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ObtainData2(string input){}
```